# Dropdownlist on gridview updating only first value to the database ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am looking for the solution to this problem from many days, please help. 
I have a grid view and have five dropdownlist on it. I have edit update and cancel edit buttons on each row.
Drop down list is updating the database, but only first value in the dropdownlist even when user select second, third or any other value from the dropdownlist.

What could possible be the reason for this. Here is my row Edit/ CancelEdit and Updating Events.

```
    protected void gvCustomers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       BindData();
    }

    protected void gvCustomers_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }

    protected void gvCustomers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {           
        Label lblCustId = (Label)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("cust_id");
        DropDownList ddlCsm = (DropDownList)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CSM");
        DropDownList ddlSrCsm = (DropDownList)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("SrCSM");
        DropDownList ddlDE = (DropDownList)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DE");
        DropDownList ddlAE = (DropDownList)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AE");
        DropDownList ddlTE = (DropDownList)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TE");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "Update SOME_TABLE SET CSM= @CSM, SrCSM= @SrCSM ,DE=@DE,AE=@AE,TE=@TE where cust_id=@cust_id";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CSM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCsm.SelectedItem.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SrCSM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSrCsm.SelectedItem.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlAE.SelectedItem.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDE.SelectedItem.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlTE.SelectedItem.Value;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }                 
            }
            catch
            { }
            gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }        
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appeciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Where are you loading your Grid View? In Page_Load ?

Comment: Have you use "if (!IsPostBack){ LoadGridFunc(); }" ?
If not, try it..

Comment: yes I just tried it still same...database is update by only first value in the dropdownList and not any other.

Comment: Apparently The answer to this is wired and I dont understand why it happened. WHen I Closed down Visual Studios and started it again it worked. I did not made any changes to the code.. This code is right. But yes including PostBack check on Page_Load. This might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

just fill the dropdowns on the click of edit button and then use on rowupdating event and use ddl.SelectedValue instead of ddl.SelectedItem.Value. You will find the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

Your Drop Downs are probably getting re-set in your Page_Load event. If they are, load them when the page is not in postback, like so:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
//set drop downs
}
```